# How to solve this integral equation $\frac{a}{b} = c + \int \frac{a(b)}{d} \mathrm{d}b + \int \frac{b(a)}{d} \mathrm{d}a$

Tags: integration

I need help with this: 
a and b are functions of one another.  c and d are real constants.

$$\frac{a}{b} = c + \int \frac{a(b)}{d} \mathrm{d}b + \int \frac{b(a)}{d} \mathrm{d}a$$

I would like to find a(b) or b(a).  Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can go [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some info on how to use $\LaTeX$ here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Disclaimer

I'll leave all restrictions that may apply at every step to you.
\begin{align}
\int \frac {a\ db}d + \int \frac {b\ da}{d} = \frac 1d \left( \int a\ db + \int a'b\ db\right ) = \frac 1d \left( \int \left [a + a'b \right ]\ db \right) = \frac 1d \left( \int \left [ab \right ]'\ db \right) = \frac {ab}d + C
\end{align}
Now, just solve the equation
\begin{align}
\frac ab = c + \frac {ab}d + C \implies a \left( d - b^2\right ) = bd \left( c + C\right) \implies a = \frac {bd \left ( c + C\right)}{d - b^2}
\end{align}

Comment: @user235851 do not hesitate to accept the answer if you think it solved your problem.

Comment: Sorry, is it the green check?  Total noob here.